# Joomla 4 - Module Backend Subform subform-row-add "row" not available

Tags: javascript, custom-module, module-params, joomla-4

while updating one of my modules for J4 i recently noticed that the repeatable subform field no longer provides the added "row" in JS. Working JS for J!3.x:

```
$(document).on('subform-row-add', function(event, row){ console.log(row); }
```

logs in J!3 something like:

```
<div class="subform-repeatable-group…m-repeatable-group-sr-0" data-base-name="watched" data-group="watched1" data-new="true"> ...
```

in J!4 it returns undefined.

I did not found any information in the web - did anyone noticed this aswell?

Comment: If you are interested in more: The event is created in the file [/build/media_source/system/js/fields/joomla-field-subform.w-c.es6.js](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/e770fe3eae3bf7c762ddff2001443815fdf71c7a/build/media_source/system/js/fields/joomla-field-subform.w-c.es6.js#L209)

Comment: To clarify my housekeeping, I have converted astridx's link-only answer to a comment because answers must not merely redirect traffic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way the event is invoked is slightly different for Joomla 4.
You can use the following:

```
$(document).on('subform-row-add', function(event) {
    console.log(event.detail.row);
});
```

Or native ES6+ Javascript (preferred):

```
document.addEventListener('subform-row-add', ({ detail: { row } }) => {
    console.log(row);
});
```